# Sorting and Counting Elements in OpenCL

Tags: sorting, count, opencl

I want to create an OpenCL kernel that sorts and counts millions of ulong. 
There is a particular algorithm that fits my needs or should I go for an hash table?

To be clear, given the following input:

```
[42, 13, 9, 42]
```

I would like to get an output like this:

```
[(9,1), (13,1), (42,2)]
```

My first idea was to modify the Counting Sort - which already counts in order to sort - but because of the wide range of ulongs it requires too much memory. Bitonic or Radix sort plus something to count elements could be a way but I miss a fast way to count the elements. Any suggestions on this?

Extra notes:

- I'm developing using an NVIDIA Tesla K40C GPU and a Terasic DE5-Net FPGA. So far the main goal is to make it work on the GPU but I'm also interested in solutions that might be a nice fit for FPGAs.
- I know that some values inside the range of ulong aren't used so we can use them to mark invalid elements or duplicates.
- I want to consume the output from the GPU using multiple threads in the CPU so a would like to avoid any solution that require some post-processing (in the host side I mean) that has data dependencies spread around the output.

Comment: Are you removing duplicate elements during the sorting process? And are you okay wrapping each ulong in a struct that adds 1 byte to each ulong? alternatively, are you okay sacrificing 2 - 4 bits from each of the ulongs? If either of these are okay, I think that I have an O(log(n)^2) solution -- the same as bitonic sort.

Comment: Removing duplicates: yes. As shown in the example, I would like to have just a list with the items plus a counter. Which well . . . it can also be obtained counting first and sorting then.

Wrapping each ulong in a struct that adds 1 byte to each ulong: Well indeed, I do need to store the counters in somewhere right? If you would be kind to share your solution I will be very grateful.

Comment: First sort, even with duplicates, just sort use a low memory algorithm. Then duplicates will be groupped together, so you can count them and group them, and I have no clue how to do this fast on OpenCL....

Comment: "Bitonic or Radix sort plus something to count elements could be a way but I miss a fast way to count the elements"

Answer (score 4):

This solution requires two passes of the bitonic sort to both count the duplicates as well as remove them (well move them to the end of the array). Bitonic sort is `O(log(n)^2)`, so this then will run with time complexity `2(log(n)^2)`, which shouldn't be a problem unless you are running this in a loop.

Create a simple struct for each of the elements, to include the number of duplicates, and if the element has been added as a duplicate, something like:

```c
// Note: If you are worried about space, or know that there 
// will only be a few duplicates for each element, then 
// make the count element smaller
typedef struct {
  cl_ulong value;
  cl_ulong count : 63;
  cl_ulong seen  : 1; 
} Element;
```

**Algorithm:**

You can start by creating a comparison function which will move duplicates to the end, and count the duplicates if they are you to be added to the total count for the element. This is the logic behind the comparison function:

1. If one element is a duplicate and another is not, return that the non-duplicate element is smaller (regardless of the values), which will move all duplicates to the end.
2. If the elements are duplicates and the right element has not been marked a duplicate (`seen=0`), then add the right element's count to the left element's count and set the right element as a duplicate (`seen=1`). This has the effect of moving the total count of an element with a specific value to the leftmost element in the array with that value, and all duplicates with that value to the end.
3. Otherwise return that the element with the smaller value, is smaller.

The comparison function would look like:

```c
bool compare(const Element* E1, const Element* E2) {
  if (!E1->seen && E2->seen) return true;  // E1 smaller
  if (!E2->seen && E1->seen) return false; // E2 smaller

  // If the elements are duplicates and the right element has 
  // not yet been "seen" by an element with the same value 
  if (E1->value == E2->value && !E2->seen) {
    E1->count += E2->count;   
    E2->seen = 1;
    return true;
  }

  // They aren't duplicates, and either
  // neither has been seen, or both have
  return E1->value < E2->value;
}
```

Bitonic sort has a specific structure, which can be nicely illustrated with a diagram. In the diagram, each element is referred to by a 3-tuple `(a,b,c)` where `a = value`, `b = count`, and `c = seen`.

Each diagram shows one run of bitonic sort on the array (vertical lines denote a comparison between elements, and horizontal lines move right to the next stage of the bitonic sort). Using the diagram and the above comparison function and logic, you should be able to convince yourself that this does what is required.

Run 1: [image: Bitonic Sort Run 1]

Run 2: [image: Bitonic Sort Run 2]

At the end of run 2, all elements are arranged by value. Duplicates with `seen = 1` are at the end, and duplicates with `seen = 0` are in their correct place and `count` is the number of other elements with the same value.

**Implementation:**

The diagrams are color coded to illustrate the sub-processes of bitonic sort. I'll call the blue blocks a phase (there are three phases in each run in the diagrams). In general, there will be `ceil(log(N))` phases for each run. Each phase consists of a number of green block (I'll call these `out-in` blocks, because the shape of the comparisons is out to in), and red blocks (I'll call these `constant` blocks, because the distance between elements to compare remains constant).

From the diagram, the `out-in` block size (elements in each block) starts at 2 and doubles in each pass. The `constant` block size for each pass starts at half the `out-in` block size (in the second (blue block) phase, there are 2 elements in each of the four red blocks, because the green blocks have a size of 4) and halves for each successive vertical lines of red block within the phase. Also, the number of successive vertical lines of the `constant` (red) blocks in a phase is always the same as the phase number with 0 indexing (0 vertical lines of red blocks for phase 0, 1 vertical line of red bocks for phase 1, and 2 vertical lines of red blocks for phase 2 -- each vertical line is an iteration of calling that kernel).

You can then make kernels for the `out-in` passes, and the `constant` passes, then invoke the kernels from the host side (because you need to constantly synchronise, which is a disadvantage, but you should still see large performance improvements over sequential implementations).

From the host side, the overall bitonic sort might look like:

```c
cl_uint num_elements = 4; // Set number of elements
cl_uint phases       = (cl_uint)ceil((float)log2(num_elements));
cl_uint out_in_block_size = 2;
cl_uint constant_block_size;

// Set the elements_buffer, which should have been created with
// with clCreateBuffer, as the first kernel argument, and the 
// number of elements as the second kernel argument
clSetKernelArg(out_in_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)(&elements_buffer));
clSetKernelArg(out_in_kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_uint), (void*)(&num_elements));
clSetKernelArg(constant_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)(&elements_buffer));
clSetKernelArg(constant_kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_uint), (void*)(&num_elements));

// For each pass
for (unsigned int phase = 0; phase < phases; ++phase) { 
  //  -------------------- Green Part ------------------------ //

  // Set the out_in_block size for the kernel
  clSetKernelArg(out_in_kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_int), (void*)(&out_in_block_size));

  // Call the kernel - command_queue is the clCommandQueue 
  // which should have been created during cl setup 
  clEnqueNDRangeKernel(command_queue    , // clCommandQueue  
                       out_in_kernel    , // The kernel
                       1                , // Work dim = 1 since 1D array
                       NULL             , // No global offset
                       &global_work_size,
                       &local_work_size ,
                       0                ,
                       NULL             ,
                       NULL);
  barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE); // Synchronise

  // ---------------------- End Green Part -------------------- //

  // Set the block size for constant blocks based on the out_in_block_size
  constant_block_size = out_in_block_size / 2;

  //  --------------------  Red Part  ------------------------ // 

  for (unsigned int i  0; i < phase; ++i) {
    // Set the constant_block_size as a kernel argument
    clSetKernelArg(constant_kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_int), (void*)(&constant_block_size));

    // Call the constant kernel
    clEnqueNDRangeKernel(command_queue    , // clCommandQueue  
                         constant_kernel  , // The kernel
                         1                , // Work dim = 1 since 1D array
                         NULL             , // No global offset
                         &global_work_size,
                         &local_work_size ,
                         0                ,
                         NULL             ,
                         NULL);
  barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE); // Synchronise

  // Update constant_block_size for next iteration
  constant_block_size /= 2; 
  }
  // ------------------- End Red Part ---------------------- //
}
```

And then the kernels would be something like (you also need to put the struct typedef in the kernel file so that the OpenCL compiler know what 'Element' is):

```c
__global void out_in_kernel(__global Element* elements, unsigned int num_elements, unsigned int block_size) {
  const unsigned int idx_upper = // index of upper element in diagram.
  const unsigned int idx_lower = // index of lower element in diagram

  // Check that both indices are in range (this depends on thread mapping)
  if (idx_upper is in range && index_lower is in range) {
    // Do the comparison
    if (!compare(elements + idx_upper, elements + idx_lower) {
      // Swap the elements 
    }
  }
}
```

The constant_kernel will look the same, but the thread mapping (how you determine `idx_upper` and `idx_lower`) will be different. There are many ways you can map the threads to the elements generally to mimic the diagrams (note that the number of threads required is half the total number of elements, since each thread can do one comparison).

Another consideration is how to make the thread mapping general (so that if you have a number of elements which is not a power of two the algorithm doesn't break).

Comment: @nicolacdnll I didn't include how to map the threads for bitonic sort as it requires a lengthy explanation and the answer was already long. It can also depend on the number of cores you have, which effects the global and local group sizes. If you would like to know how to map threads in OpenCL specifically for bitonic sort, then additionally ask that question and I will give an answer to that.

Comment: Not Bad! I do not expect to have a number of elements that is a power of 2 but I will try to implement also this solution and let's see how it goes.

Comment: @nicolacdnll it doesn't have to be a power of 2, you just need to make sure that in the kernels you make an appropriate check. I've implemented this in cuda for a non power of 2 array, but the index calculation was a bit tricky!

Comment: So far I implemented only a simple Bitonic and, sadly, it takes too long slowing things down. Of course, implement the second phase will only make thing worst so I don't think I will go in this way. 

For sure the solution works and is really nice but it really takes too much time.

Comment: @nicolacdnll, the solution is 2log(n)^2 which is only 1000 comparisons for 10 elements! I find that very strange, since when I implemented it with CUDA it was very fast! The sorting method doesn't really matter though, just use the same comparison operator and sort twice with any method and you should get a correctly sorted array with duplicated counted.

Comment: In general it's fast and with a K40c I get a throughput of 100 Mkeys/sec. This said, it's slow for what I'm doing. Which brings me to the conclusion that also any other solutions might be slow for what I'm doing.

Comment: RobClucas : If you would like to know how to map threads in OpenCL specifically for bitonic sort, then additionally ask that question and I will give an answer to that. – RobClucas Feb 2, 2016 at 15:23
 
 I know this a very old post but I would appreciate that you take time for that threads mapping.
 And also do you think it would be possible to do all the work from within a master kernel using the OpnCL 2 's new function "enqueue_kernel()" which permit calling a kernel from a parent kernel?

Answer (score 1):

How about [boost.compute](https://boostorg.github.io/compute/boost/compute/sort.html) or [VexCL](http://ddemidov.github.io/vexcl/)? Both provide sorting algorithms.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a solution to count duplicates in these library. Did I miss it?

Answer (score 1):

Mergesort works quite well on GPUs and you could modify it to sort key+count instead of keys only. During merging you would then also check if do keys are identical and if yes, fuse them into a single key during merge. (If you merge [9/c:1, 42/c:1] and [13/c:1,42/c:1] you would get [9/c:1,13/c:1,42/c:2] )
You might have to use parallel prefix sum to remove the gaps caused by fusing keys.

Or: Use a regular GPU sort first, mark all keys where the key to its right is different (this is only true at the last key of each unique key), use parallel prefix sum to get consecutive indexes for all unique keys and note their position in the sorted array. Then you only need to subtract the index of the previous unique key to get the count.

Comment: I like more the idea behind the second option because is more creative. But it doesn't really fit my needs. It wasn't specified in the original post (so of course you couldn't know) but I want to consume the output using multiple threads in the CPU.

About the first option I can do better because I know that some values into the range of the ulong aren't used. This said, at the end of each merge phase, if n fusions occurred I store in the last n elements an "invalid value". Plus when merging I consider that I'm at the end of a sub-list also when I have an element with an "invalid value".

Comment: My solution does not require postprocessing on the CPU. You can do everything on the GPU, including prefix-sums and substracting indexes. You can and should do the prefix sums and subtracting of indexes in the same kernel, that last kernel will produce results that can directly be used by the CPU or even other GPU kernels. The complete algorithm requires the use of different kernels, but you can enqueue all these from the CPU at the same time and your multiple kernels just need to check if the last kernel has already finished to check if their data is ready.

Comment: My bad you're right!  Well I can en-queue the kernels and synch them with with events as well.